# Dynamically generated field in SqlAlchemy model with Postgres

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, data-modeling

I want to create a table with a column for each hour of the day of Float type. 
How do I get rid of this verbose syntax:

```
from app import db

class HourlySchedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )

    h0 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h1 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h2 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h3 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h4 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h5 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h6 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h7 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h8 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h9 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h10 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h11 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h12 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h13 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h14 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h15 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h16 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h17 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h18 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h19 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h20 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h21 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h22 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    h23 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
```

Another question is how do I enforce checks on the values (e.g. 0 <= value <=1)?

As validation? Then how do i set validation neatly for 24 fields?

Can I instead add a check constraint with SqlAlchemy?

Comment: If you really want to have 24 columns in your table, there is nothing wrong with the verbose approach. You can write a [validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators) for limits checking.

Comment: Then I will post the question "Dynamically generated validators in SqlAlchemy"

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to realize that a `class` block is just a block of code, so you can put loops in there:

```
class HourlySchedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    for i in range(24):
        locals()["h{}".format(i)] = db.Column(db.Float)

    @validates(*("h{}".format(i) for i in range(24)))
    def _validate(self, k, h):
        assert 0 <= h <= 1
        return h
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to play around with the order of calling `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, but this should theoretically work.

As for validation, the good thing about the `validates` decorator is that it takes multiple column names, so we can achieve dynamic field creation and validation like so:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates


class HourlySchedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.colstrings = []

        for hour in range(0, 24):
            colstring = "h{}".format(hour)
            setattr(self, colstring, db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True))
            self.colstrings.append(colstring)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @validates(*self.colstrings)
    def validate_hours(self, key, hour): 
        assert 0 < hour < 1
        return hour
```

One thing I'd like to note, however, is that this is actually greatly increases the complexity of a rather simple concept. Instead of hiding model details, which are meant to be verbose so devs can easily understand model > table mappings, it might make more sense to either list out every column, or to rethink how you're structuring your data.